# Как оформить "как-как" в ответной реплике диалога?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно оформить в диалоге словосочетание "как-как"? Дефис, тире, пробел, кавычки? 
Диалог такой:

*— Ну и как успехи?*

*— Как-как? Сижу выбираю.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем примере, на мой взгляд, КАК, КАК можно написать и через запятую, и через дефис в зависимости от интонации.

***— Ну и как успехи?
— Как, как... Сижу выбираю.***

Или:

***— Ну и как успехи?
— Как-как... Сижу выбираю.*** [Как-как через дефис, без пробелов]

Если вы чётко разделяете интонацией эти два слова, то КАК, КАК?  пишется через запятую, например:

***Хорошо бы было нащупать, где он стоял. ― Как, как вы сказали? Директор останавливается, вынимает записную книжечку, просит повторить.*** [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 2 (1978)] - пример из Нацкорпуса.

Если вы произносите оба слова как бы скороговоркой, то пишется через дефис:

***Он, как клушка, закудахтал! "То есть как же так? Как-как? Смольный! Да это же государственные деньги!*** [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 3 (1978)] - пример из Нацкорпуса.

В орфографическом словаре Бархударова, Ожегова, Шапиро 1973 года написания через дефис КАК-КАК нет.

В орфографическом словаре 1999 года [Академик](https://lopatin.academic.ru/48666/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA):

как-как
к'ак-к'ак

Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999

Answer (score 0):

Правильно пишется "как-как". Ссылка: http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/kak-kak/?q=532&n=47787